# D3 Integration with Angular: "Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute x"

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm attempting to bind SVG attributes using AngularJS. I have the following code for a resize handle of a shape:

```
// S handle.
var s_handle = d3.select(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect"))
    .attr("id", "s-resize")
    .attr("x", "{{(objects['" + id + "'].w - (scope.dragHandle.width / 2))}}")
    .attr("y", "{{(objects['" + id + "'].h - (scope.dragHandle.width / 2))}}")
    .attr(scope.dragHandle)
    .attr("cursor", "s-resize")
    .call(sresize);              

$compile(s_handle.node())(scope);
element.append(s_handle);
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute x="{{(objects['9b320170-6365-4f40-801d-a7a5c6b936f9'].w - (scope.dragHandle.width / 2))}}" d3.min.js:1
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="{{(objects['9b320170-6365-4f40-801d-a7a5c6b936f9'].h - (scope.dragHandle.width / 2))}}" d3.min.js:1
```

I tried removing the append step to isolate the issue - and it looks like the issue actually happens when I set the `x` and `y` attributes, even before the Angular compile stage.

Note that I have this method working with another SVG object using the `transform` attribute, which natively accepts a string.

Has anyone run into this problem before? Are there any solutions? Thank you.

Edit: Been stepping through and it looks like $compile` isn't actually changing the element at all. Could this be because the element is invalid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this was related to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2061

It was solved in that issue as well.

SVG elements use an XML-based schema, and are namespaced, and as such have validation rules. Certain attributes can't take an Angular interpolated directive because they expect a numeric value, and the browser validates this before Angular ever has a chance to catch it (even if the element is created and not appended to the DOM yet).

If anyone runs into this issue, hopefully this answer will help.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful!  Just to add a simplified version of the pull request discussion: when you want to do Angular interpolation on attributes of SVG elements, prepend the attribute name with `ng-attr-`

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! And thanks @ChrisLoer for summarizing. I've been banging my head on this for a few hours until I finally sorted that it was something in this domain. (No pun intended).