# svg invalid value for <path>

Tags: angularjs, svg

I have a problem with typing the SVG path d = "". I do not understand this message of error.

html:

```
<svg style="height:300px">
   <path d="{{ room.coordinate }}" ng-repeat="room in rooms" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
```

SVG path: M 150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z

Error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="{{ room.coordinate }}" jquery.min.js:3
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="{{ room.coordinate }}" angular.min.js:23
```

Comment: Use `ng-attr-d` instead of the `d` attribute.

Comment: nice works, thank you

Comment: @Blackhole you should post it as a proper answer, this really helped!

Answer (score 4):

This relates to this question: [D3 Integration with Angular: "Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409841/d3-integration-with-angular-error-invalid-value-for-rect-attribute-x)

And this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2061

For every `<svg>` attribute, `ng-attr-<name>={{<evaluated value>}}` should be used instead of `<name>={{<evaluated value>}}`.